# Is utilitarian a negative descriptor?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, emotions

I've mostly used and seen "utilitarian" in a negative sense: something that only exists for its function, and specifically for those functions. In other words, something that is single-purpose.

[utilitarian](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/utilitarian)

> designed to be useful rather than decorative:

But what if I wanted to describe something positively, could utilitarian be an apt adjective? I often see phrases like "utility focused" or "utility oriented" as positive, but utilitarian as negative. Aren't they the same?

For example: "I worked at Big Tech Company where I designed and developed utility focused modules" sounds positive or neutral. "I worked at Big Tech Company where I designed and developed utilitarian modules" sounds *pretty bad*.

Comment: Generally I've heard "utilitarian" used to mean that aesthetics were neglected. For example utilitarian buildings or vehicles. But if you're talking about something that isn't meant to have an aesthetic aspect, then I (at least) wouldn't take the adjective as negative.

Comment: I suppose the standard definition, 'designed to be useful rather than attractive [or comfortable]' doesn't sound too appetising, but the term is often used non-pejoratively.

Comment: I edited to provide required research, but the definitions do not appear to limit the object to a sing le use. For me, utilitarian could refer to a Swiss Army knife, which haas many uses combined in a single tool.

Comment: "I worked at Big Tech Company where I designed and developed functional components."

Comment: To me, "utilitarian" also suggests "no better than it needs to be".

Comment: @ThePhoton, the word is, as a matter of pragmatics, usually used for things that **are** expected to be aesthetically pleasing, but fail to be, and thus usually conveys some mild criticism. For things that are not at all meant to have an aesthetic aspect, some other term is more likely to be used, such as *useful*, *efficient*, *no-frills*, or the OP's *utility focused*.

Comment: Just for the record, *utilitarian* also has another sense, which is clearly not the one intended by the OP: in accordance with the philosophical theory of utilitarianism. Used in that sense, the word is neutral in itself, but may convey criticism when used among the opponents of that theory.

Comment: Like most things it's good when it's wanted and bad when it's not. Deadly rat poison is good, deadly breakfast cereal is bad.

Comment: @jsw29 you are correct, however, the dictionary definition of utilitarian is sometimes synonymous with utilitarianism, as I found to my surprise.

Comment: @ThePhoton I think you have an answer there. The sense of aesthetic neglect is exactly what comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the core of the question is an historical/etymological fact.  The word *utilitarian* is familiar students of moral philosophy was coined by the 18th century philosopher, David Hume, who was, in effect, re-introducing an idea first recorded by by the Alexandrian Greek philosopher, Epicurus (*Epikouros*).  Epicurus, discarding the idea that ethical values are given to humans by the gods, claimed that human behaviour is driven by the pursuit of happiness/pleasure.  Naturally, the casual reader would and did easily assume (wrongly) that a kind of amoral selfish hedonism was being recommended and the name Epicurus lives on in the word *epicurian*, which still suggests indulgence in good wine and food.  The original word is explained in Etymonline as follows.

> 1781, coined by Jeremy Bentham (1748-1832) from utility + -arian on the model of + unitarian, etc. One guided by the doctrine of the greatest happiness for the greatest number. From 1802 as an adjective; in the general sense "having regard to utility rather than beauty," from 1847.

In the 19th century the philosopher, John Stewart Mill, adopted the word *utilitarianism* to name his theory that moral choice involves aiming at the *greatest utility*, that amounting happiness of the greatest number.

Just as superficial interpretation of Epicurus' *hedonic* version of morality fell victim to the superficial idea that Epicurus was recommended self-indulgence as a way of life, so anxious folk in the 19th century picked up on the idea of *utility* and though Mill was advocating a heartless idea of what morality involves.

Today, the Cambridge English Dictionary online gives a prime definition which carries a pejorative edge:

> designed to be useful rather than decorative

The examples that follow show that it is difficult use the adjective without a pejorative edge an any context which has more that pure practical usefulness in view.  The Collins begins with the JS Mill philosophy and then proceeds to the mildly or more seriously pejorative contemporary aesthetic usage.

> Utilitarian objects and buildings are designed to be useful rather than attractive.

It gives the example:-

> Bruce's office is a corner one, utilitarian and unglamorous.

It seems that the pejorative aesthetic usage tends to predominate, therefore, and that only in writing explicitly connected with ethical and possibly aesthetic theory and to ve read by people who understand this can you use the word *utilitarian* in its original sense.

Even as part of an aesthetic theory in which readers can be expected to understand (say) visual beauty as that which gives the greatest visual pleasure to the greatest number, The word 'utilitarian' sounds out of place, because it clashes with what so many speakers understand by the word.  The language has moved on.

Answer (score 2):

To consolidate what's already in this thread in the comments and question:

Yes, utilitarian has a mildly negative connotation - often implying that the thing is unappealing or neglects aesthetics where the speaker would have preferred to see them considered, or that it's design or functionality is unoriginal. While the trait of *being* purpose-focused is often, as you pointed out, a positive trait representing a well-designed thing for its role, the term utilitarian is not used as praise except in the most lukewarm manner - another term, like the ones you mentioned, is used instead.

A noteworthy caveat is that you'll see utilitarian used for moderate praise in conjunction with another adjective to express that something does its job well but is uninspiring, as in 'utilitarian but effective' or 'efficient, if utilitarian, solution' - in this sense utilitarian is used similarly to mundane or uninspiring.

Comment: This reads like opinion, something we don't actually do here very well. Please back up your thoughts with some citations, sources, and where possible links. If you have questions regarding Q&A format at EL&U, feel free to visit our [Help Page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) If you are trying to create a summation of the comments, I recommend posting a WIKI answer.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ Thank you for the advice! To clarify: is the issue that what I posted is opinion rather than fact, or is the issue that what I posted is factual (if true) but isn't adequately sourced for verification?

Comment: Two things can be true.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ Ouch

Answer (score 1):

It can be used in both positive and negative contexts. For example, it is clearly positive in [$30 or so can buy a whole lot of fun, utilitarian software](https://www.arkansasonline.com/news/2020/may/23/30-or-so-can-buy-a-whole-lot-of-fun-uti/). Another example with positive connotation is "We find developers are very utilitarian, very practical" (describing people who aren't attracted to a "sensationalist clickbait headline") on the [SO blog](https://resources.stackoverflow.co/topic/client-stories/case-study-twilio/).

It's used negatively in [Ask HN: Why Are Programmer Design Tastes So Utilitarian?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=34246340) (in which, the author elaborates that those tastes seem decades old and unreadable).

On a resume, it's very generic, almost like a buzzword. You provided no context as to what the modules do (and why "utilitarian" should be interpreted positively). Do they help people make fewer mistakes? Automate away hours of work? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

The question is about the words "utility" **and** "utilitarian":

> I often see phrases like "utility focused" or "utility oriented" as positive, but utilitarian as negative. Aren't they the same?

The examples provided are in the context of engineering. I can't tell if they are related to software or other (e.g. electrical, mechanical) engineering. There are no pejorative connotations with having developed a utility module, be it for software development or for electric power load balancing. The adjective, utilitarian, can have unintended unfavorable connotations associated with a philosophical outlook that is sometimes held by software engineers (and many other people). Even in that context, it isn't necessarily bad or good, but people have strong opinions about it. More on that in a moment.

**Utility as a noun**

- Utility as the [utility modules](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/utility) mentioned by OP:

> A software program designed to perform a single task or a small range
> of tasks, often to help manage and tune computer hardware, an
> operating system or application software.

Clearly, there's nothing negative about [Narrator which is a Text-to-Speech utility](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-configure-and-use-text-to-speech-in-windows-xp-and-in-windows-vista-f6970cc6-07b7-9130-efdc-66385d38a4e1) for Windows users who are blind or have impaired vision.

- Utility as a monopoly distributer of a service to the public (or many consumers) through shared infrastructure, e.g. electric, water, or gas company.
- Utility as something that is [notably useful](https://twitter.com/RobertsFarmEq/status/1250846642288427008), e.g. locomotives have enduring utility for railroads, or a [utility player in sports](https://www.sports-king.com/dictionary.php?q=utility-player) (a person who is uncommonly useful and versatile).

There is nothing negative about a utility, regardless of definition.

**Utilitarian as an adjective**

- Utilitarian describes something that is designed to be useful or practical rather than attractive. It might not be nice-looking or have lots of features, but it is functional, i.e. it gets the job done. Note that that meaning is the [THIRD definition for the word as an adjective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/utilitarian#dictionary-entry-2) in Merriam-Webster's Dictionary and the [SECOND definition for word as an adjective](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/utilitarian) in the Macmillan Dictionary. It is the first definition in Collins Dictionary and the Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus.
- The first and second definitions of **utilitarian** in Merriam-Webster's Dictionary are **"of or relating to or advocating utilitarianism"** and **"marked by utilitarian views or practices"**. Macmillan's definition of **utilitarian** is **"attitudes or principles are based on the belief that something is morally right if it helps a majority of people"**. In other words, **it is an actual definition of the philosophy**. (Utilitarianism is a well-established ethical philosophy first written about at length by Jeremy Bentham and John Stuart Mill in the 18th and 19th centuries.)

Be careful in using the adjective "utilitarian" because it can mean something that has aspects of the noun "utility" **OR** it can mean pertaining to or being supportive of the moral/ethical philosophy of utilitarianism. The latter has its adherents and detractors, and can be interpreted in positive or negative ways.

These are examples of how utilitarian (if taken to mean utilitarianism) can have either positive or negative meanings. Investopedia describes utilitarianism as not accounting for things like feelings and emotions, culture, or justice. According to the [University of Texas at Austen](https://ethicsunwrapped.utexas.edu/glossary/utilitarianism), "It is the only moral framework that can be used to justify military force or war... it has trouble accounting for values such as justice and individual rights". In contrast, [Stanford University Philosophy Encyclopedia](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/utilitarianism-history/) describes it as "one of the most powerful and persuasive approaches to normative ethics in the history of philosophy".

Comment: In the context of utilitarianism the ethical philosophy, it bears mentioning that morality is a wicked problem; for *any* ethical philosophy, situations can be constructed in which the philosophy gives an answer opposite to natural intuition - every theory is seriously flawed, and this is widely understood in the field.